# How can I Invoke a function/method from a .so file in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

I am trying to implement [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) into my Android app. 
I already have the prebuilt **.so** files that I need.

I just can't figure out how to invoke one of the many functions in the library. 
Here is what I have thus far:

I've placed each of the **.so** files under a jniLibs folder
[image]

Here is my gradle file
[image: Here is my gradle file]

From there, I load the library like this:

```
static {
    Log.e("jni", "starting");
    System.loadLibrary("avdevice");
    Log.e("jni", "finished");
}
```

It loads successfully. So far so good.

Next, I look at the .h file to find the methods that I can call. Please note, I am assuming that this .h file is bundled into the .so file. This might be where it all falls apart.

```
/**
* Return the LIBAVDEVICE_VERSION_INT constant.
*/

unsigned avdevice_version(void);
```

Since I now know the method name I need to call I place this in my code:

```
public native int avdeviceVersion();
```

When I try and call `avdeviceVersion();` I get this error message back:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.my.app.ApplicationContext.avdeviceVersion() (tried Java_com_my_app_ApplicationContext_avdeviceVersion and Java_com_my_app_ApplicationContext_avdeviceVersion__)
```

Now, I realize that `Java_com_my_app_ApplicationContext_avdeviceVersion` doesn't match the method name in the .h file. But, I'm left clueless how to make it match and what to do next. If you know, please explain it as thoroughly as possible. Assume I know nothing :)

**Update**

I added the Android.mk file as well as the Application.mk, I also added a Jni bridge called `video.c`.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_my_app_jni_VideoKit_version(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jobjectArray args) {
return (*env)->avdevice_version();}
```

My Android.mk is this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := video.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

With these changes the result is the same.

Comment: So are you calling your .so library methods without a wrapper on the C side to handle the JNI bridge?

Comment: @MorrisonChang hey, I have a feeling this is where I went wrong. Can you explain further what you mean? All i did was compile ffmpeg into .so files. Do i need to update the ffmpeg library with a wrapper?

Comment: I would confirm with a simple "hello world JNI" example that your setup/configuration is correct and then see if your library conforms to JNI. My guess is that you are missing the 'bridge code' i.e. going from Java double to C/C++ double, etc which is covered in all JNI tutorials but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure the environment for using c/c++ classes.
You need CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk / Application.mk.

Then, You should make a class for linking java class and native class.

[This link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts) could help you.

As the error messages says, 
`jint Java_{PACKAGE_NAME}_{CLASS_NAME}_{FUNCTION_NAME}(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)` is needed. And you could call `avdevice_version()` inside the function.

### Update

In Android.mk, first you make prebuilt shared library, and then make linking shared library

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := static_avdevice # you can change the name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = avdevice.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include # header file directory
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include # header file directory
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jniLinker
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := video.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := static_avdevice
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then, load library. `System.loadLibrary("jniLinker");`

And, there are a lot of samples in googlesamples github.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs
This is the code sample for using 3rd-party library. (But it uses CMake.)

Comment: I'll try this tonight. I'll let you know tomorrow what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @ss.techie I took a stab at what you suggested. Please see the "Update" on the original post.  Is this what you intended?